# “Built-in” or “In-built”

Tags: word-choice, word-order

Is there any difference between using *in-built* or *built-in*? Is one more correct than the other, or does it depend on the context, or ”house style”?

> This oven comes with a *built-in* extractor fan.
>
> This oven comes with an *in-built* extractor fan.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of those ones where Google, whatever faults it might have, does tell you something significant:

```
"built-in extractor fan"      643,000 results
"in-built extractor fan"          137 results
```

Subjectively, from the first ten results, it looks like the "in-built" hits are largely from the UK. I've never even heard of an "in-built extractor fan".

Just at a guess I would think that "in-built" would go with "ability", so I tried it on Google:

```
"built-in ability"  216,000 results
"in-built ability"   75,500 results
```

Comment: Yes: I think that "in-built" is nearly always used figuratively, to mean "innate", whereas "built-in" is used of made things.

Comment: Just for context, I'm in the UK and it's always been "built-in" rather than "in-built".

Answer (score 21):

Actually, this is written "[inbuilt](http://www.wordnik.com/words/inbuilt)" and not "in-built".
It is an [old (1923) chiefly British synonym for built-in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inbuilt).

- Constructed as part of a larger unit; not detachable:  a built-in cabinet.
- Forming a permanent or essential element or quality: a built-in escape clause

Example:

> "Of course, even the most able driver in the most dynamically competent car can sometimes find his or herself in a situation where a collision is inevitable, so with this in mind the Spark was designed with high levels of passive safety inbuilt from the outset."

—[Automotive Headlines](http://www.theautochannel.com/news/2010/02/08/464892.html)

Comment: "in-built" is simply "inbuilt" misspelled.