# Is "inbuilt" a word? Is it alright to use it or should I use "built in"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, hyphenation, is-it-a-word, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I searched and found this: [“Built-in” or “In-built”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/built-in-or-in-built), which says *inbuilt* is fine. But [in a reddit comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/marketing/comments/1nf5y6/need_your_feedback_i_have_built_a_simplified/cci27ud), I was told that I should use *built in* instead of *inbuilt*. Which is correct? I am using the word *inbuilt* on http://www.inboundio.com/features

Comment: Use *built-in*: *in-built* is not used in technical writing in the given field of software.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=builtin+function%2Cinbuilt+function&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: In the future please do not repost a question every time you find a contradicting reddit comment. This is not how Stack Exchange is supposed to work. If a question has been answered, it has been answered.

Comment: @RegDwighт - got it, won't happen again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the **Insular English** of Britain (England, Scotland, and Wales), Ireland (both the Republic and the Northern part), and surrounding bits like the Isle of Man and the Channel Islands, the preferred form is ***in-built***, hyphenated like that.  That’s the way the OED has it.

> Chiefly as **ˈin-ˌbuilt** *ppl. a.* = **built-in**

In the **North American English** of the United States and Canada, the preferred form runs the other way, making it ***built-in***. The OED says:

> **built-in**: (a) constructed to form an integral part of a larger unit, esp. of the fittings or appurtenances of a house; (b) fig. inherent, integral, innate.

My familiarity with **Antipodean English** is extremely spotty at best, but I am pretty sure that I have heard some Kiwis use the Insular form and some Ozzies use the North American form.  However, I don’t have enough experience there to say whether those were the norms or the exceptions.

O’Reilly, the tech publishing house, uses *built-in* as a matter of standard practice in its [published style guide](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html), and does so whether the word is used as an adjective or as a noun.

The reason they saw need to spell out that the word should be spelt the same way no matter its part of speech is because there is a very common tendency amongst programmers to use the unhyphenated form for the noun use.  Most commonly, they wil refer to a programming language’s built-in functions and keywords as that language’s *builtins*.  So one might say that `if` and `while`, or perhaps `sin` and `cos`, `length` and `delete`, as being some hypothetical language’s *builtins*.

But O’Reilly doesn’t like that, so spells out that one should hyphenate even there.

Comment: Apparently, InFormIT has no standard, as opposed to O'Reilly.  As an example, see [C++ in One Hour a Day, Sams Teach Yourself, 8th Edition](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-in-one-hour-a-day-sams-teach-yourself-9780789757746), Pg 46, Listing 3.5.  The insular form prevails as far as India.  Again this seems true only in technical books.

Answer (score 2):

In-built and built-in are both words.  I work with a lot of people in London and hear in-built. However I have never heard it spoken from an American - if it is it can't be popular.  Basically if you said "I am going to make some in-built bookshelves."  People would not take that to mean built-in, they would just think it was another descriptor or possibly that you flipped your words on accident.

Built-in is mainly used in the home environment in America to convey permanence (there are other uses but not common).  If you have a microwave, bookshelf, cabinet, whatever... Those things could be easily moved.  If you you have a built-in microwave, bookshelf,cabinet, whatever...  Those things are considered part of the "home" and are permanently fastened.

Comment: Any English: He has an in-built sense of justice, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is a word, but you might want to write it as *in-built*. I would also suggests writing ***an*** in-built simplifed CRM, depending on the meaning of CRM.

Comment: Do please note that ***in-built*** is a strictly insular English expression (with *insular* here meaning Britain and Ireland, Barrie: don’t worry! :), while the flipped-over version ***built-in*** prevails in North America.

Comment: _Inbuilt_, _in-built_ and _in built_ are much more frequent in the BNC than in the COCA. Interestingly, though, _builtin_, _built-in_ and _built in_ are also a little more frequent in the BNC than in the COCA. That may, of course, be because of greater use of _built in_ in constructions like ‘built in 1908’.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'built-in' refers specifically to something physical that is actually built e.g. a 'built-in wardrobe' (Americans probably call it a closet), as opposed to a free-standing one. It means that the wardrobe, cupboard, or shelving is actually fixed to the wall. The term 'in-built' can also refer to physical things, but is perhaps more often used to refer to something metaphorical such as 'an in-built problem'. e.g. 'the new state of Ambrosia brings with it all the in-built discontent associated with the separate warring elements of the population'.